# Auto indent broken lines in html

Tags: indentation

Does anyone know what settings or package I can use to make vim autoindent html if it's wider that the screen. eg. it is displaying like this:

```
<main>
  <section>
    <form action="#">
      <input type="text" class="someclassname" id="someid" value="foo" 
placeholder="" data-foo="foo" data-bar="bar" />
    </form>
  </section>
</main>
```

I would like it to indent the broken line like this:

```
<main>
  <section>
    <form action="#">
      <input type="text" class="someclassname" id="someid" value="foo" 
        placeholder="" data-foo="foo" data-bar="bar" />
    </form>
  </section>
</main>
```

or even this:

```
<main>
  <section>
    <form action="#">
      <input type="text" 
        class="someclassname" 
        id="someid" value="foo" 
        placeholder="enter something" 
        data-foo="foo" 
        data-bar="bar" />
    </form>
  </section>
</main>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: `set breakindent`

Long Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204149/smart-wrap-in-vim

Comment: Thank you, I have been looking for that setting for a couple of weeks now. it was my stay with vim or go back to php storm clincher.